# Excel - find and replace or match?

Tags: excel, excel-match

I have an Excel sheet with about 7000+ rows. Column A contains object names and column B contains location codes.
In another sheet, there are 1000 rows with column A containing location codes and column B matched, proper location names that are more conventional.

What would be the most efficient way to replace (or match in another column) those 7000+ codes with display names so that the document can become more readable?

Here's a rough [mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BzrV.png)

In other words: I'd like "Group" names from Sheet 2 to match every instance of the "Address" in Sheet 1. Sheet 2 in this case is simply a sort of a map legend.

Thank you

Comment: Likely using INDEX MATCH or XLOOKUP will resolve this, but without a proper sample it's hard for us to determine exactly what you need. Can you please mock up a sample?

Comment: https://exceljet.net/index-and-match & https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-xlookup-function .. Have a try and share how have d u get..

Comment: XLOOKUP solved it.
I had an issue with the Microsoft presentation where not only do they use a comma instead of a semicolon, but for some reason highlighting data manually works just fine but typing the area in the formula field does not and it remains grayed-out.
So it was a matter of a basic XLOOKUP function after all. Thank you very much for your suggestions!